# Remove duplicates from a sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have this code that I have been working on for a couple of hours now trying to figure out how to implement removing duplicates within the sorted array during the insertion sort. I'm trying to do this without having to re-write the whole program but as I progress it seems that I may just have to start from scratch but before I do I was hoping to see if it was possible to do this with the code below.

The question at hand is, How can I go about removing duplicates from the sorted array before putting it back into a file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace std;

//sort into an array using insertion sort
//getis info from file "numbers.txt"
//and prints the sorted numbers into "sorted_numbers.txt"
void insertSort(int a[], int length)
{
   int i, j, value;
   int old = 0;
   bool first = true;

   for(i = 1; i < length; i++)
   {
       if(first || old != a[i])
       {
           old = a[i];
           first = false;

           value = a[i];
           for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && a[j] > value; j--)
           {
               a[j + 1] = a[j];
           }
       }
       a[j + 1] = value;
   }
}

//prints out the array in 'Run I/O'
void printarray(int arg[], int length)
{
    for(int n =0; n<length; ++n)
      cout << arg[n] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

int main ()
{
    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;

    int N = 10;
    int n = 0;
    int k;
    int* a = new int(N);

    //opens the file "numbers.txt" if it exit
    //gets the chars from file and sorts them 
    //into array "a[n]" 
    in.open("numbers.txt");
    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File could not be opened FILE NOT FOUND." << std::endl;

        //creates the a new file to be read from if numbers.txt does
        //not already exist and put numbers inside of it
        //to be sorted with the InsertSort function
        out.open("numbers.txt");
        out << "1" << endl;
        out << "3" << endl;
        out << "7" << endl;
        out << "4" << endl;
        out << "2" << endl;
        out << "7" << endl;
        out << "6" << endl;
        out << "9" << endl;
        out << "5" << endl;
        out << "2" << endl;

        out.close();

        //opens the new numbers.txt file and puts the 
        //numbers into an array to be sorted
        in.open("numbers.txt");

        //runs through the items in the file and
        //puts them into an array
        int x;
        while(in >> x) 
        {
            a[n] = x;
            n++; 
        }

        printarray(a,10);
        std::cout << "Read " << n << " integers from the file." << std::endl;

        //sorts the array from when it was read 
        //to the new insertion sort array
        insertSort(a,n);

        std::cout << "Integers are sorted" << std::endl;

        //writes/creates the new sorted array to a new file
        //called "sorted_numbers.txt"
        out.open("sorted_numbers.txt");
        for(k = 0;k < n;k++)
            out << a[k] << std::endl;
            printarray(a,10);
        out.close();

        delete[] a;

        in.close();
    }
    else
    {
        int x;
        while(in >> x) 
        {
            a[n] = x;
            n++;
         }

      printarray(a,10);
      std::cout << "Read " << n << " integers from the file." << std::endl;

      insertSort(a,n);

      std::cout << "Integers are sorted" << std::endl;

      //writes/creates the new sorted array to a new file
      //called "sorted_numbers.txt"
      out.open("sorted_numbers.txt");
      for(k = 0;k < n;k++)
          out << a[k] << std::endl;   
          std::cout << n << " integers stored to the file." << std::endl;
          printarray(a,10);
      out.close();

      delete[] a;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use insertion sort? If you used e.g. a quicksort, you would have the advantage that during every iteration, you already partition the input into elements before the pivot and after. If you modify that to discard any elements equal to the pivot, you would solve both tasks of sorting and making unique in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `algorithm` library and a `std::vector`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  {
    std::ifstream is("numbers.txt");
    for (int i; is >> i; )
      v.push_back(i);
  }

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());

  std::ofstream of("sorted_numbers.txt");
  for (auto i : v)
    of << i << '\n';

  // Or for non-c++11
  // for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
  //   of << *i << '\n';
}
```

Or even a `std::set` for simplicity (the vector version *may* be faster, but probably won't matter much for your use case).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::set<int> s;
  {
    std::ifstream is("numbers.txt");
    for (int i; is >> i; )
      s.insert(i);
  }

  std::ofstream of("sorted_numbers.txt");
  for (auto i : s)
    of << i << '\n';

  // Or for non-c++11
  // for (std::set<int>::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
  //   of << *i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: While testing this code I get this error.  test.cpp:19:13: error: 'i' does not name a type         for (auto i : v)

Comment: @Jaybro90 What compiler are you using? Does it support c++11?

Comment: I am using jGRASP, which I should probably download a different compiler

Comment: I'll add some lines that should work if you have no c++11 support.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution worked, I also added it so that if the file 'numbers.txt' doesn't already exist it will create it then execute the sort and remove duplicates.

Comment: It should be noted that the first solution does not achieve the actual result the OP asked: removing duplicates *during* the sort operation. The second, a `std::set` accumulation, does achieve this, but not within the array sequence (because there isn't one). And the first example needn't actually *erase* the duplicates. It can simply use the result of `std::unique` as the end-iterator of an iterator dump. [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/mBcC2z)

Answer (score 2):

Insertion sort operates left to right and rotates a sub-array to the right (to place the smallest value on the left of the sub-array), while deletion of a duplicate shifts a sub-array to the left. As an alternative, I created and modified a "delete" sort (a reversed insertion sort) that operates right to left and rotates a sub-array to the left (to place the largest value on the right of the sub-array), and left shifts of a sub-array to delete duplicates.

```
void deletesort(int a[], int &length)
{
    int i, j, value;
    if(length < 2)
        return;
    for(i = length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        value = a[i];
        for (j = i+1; j < length; j++){
            if(value > a[j]){
                a[j-1] = a[j];
                continue;
            }
            if(value == a[j]){
                for( ; j < length; j++)
                    a[j-1] = a[j];
                length--;
            }
            break;
        }
        a[j-1] = value;
    }
}
```

Here's a delete sort that doesn't remove duplicates:

```
void deletesort(int a[], int length)
{
    int i, j, value;
    if(length < 2)
        return;
    for(i = length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        value = a[i];
        for (j = i+1; j < length && value > a[j]; j++)
            a[j-1] = a[j];
        a[j-1] = value;
    }
}
```